# File not saving and there's no errors - Answer at bottom

Tags: c#, file, serialization, saving-data

I started a random project today to see if I could make my own video player that used a file type that I made. Everything works apart from the creating a file from a group of images part. Here's the code below:

```
private void createBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    VideoProcessing processing = new VideoProcessing();

    List<Frame> frms = new List<Frame>();

    string[] filePaths = { };
    using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath)) {
            filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
        }
    }

    foreach (String s in filePaths) {
        frms.Add(new Frame(ImageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(s))));
    }

    Frame[] f = frms.ToArray();

    string file = "";
    using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath)) {
            file = fbd.SelectedPath + "Video2.frf";
        }
    }

    VideoFile video = new VideoFile();
    video.frames = f;
    video.name = file;

    processing.WriteToBinaryFile<VideoFile>(file, video);
}
```

I've tried debugging to see what's going on. However, everything seems normal and the lines of code are also being run the file just isn't being saved and no errors are being thrown.

Here's the VideoProcessing class

```
 public class VideoProcessing {
    private Form1 frm = new Form1();

    public void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create)) {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
        }
    }

    public T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath) {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open)) {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    public VideoFile CreateFile(string prePath) {
        VideoFile file = new VideoFile();
        int i = 0;
        file.frames = new Frame[frm.frames.Count];
        file.name = prePath;
        foreach (Frame frame in frm.frames) {
            file.frames[i] = frame;
            i++;
        }

        return file;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class VideoFile {
    public string name;
    public string extension = ".frf";
    public Frame[] frames;
}
```

ANSWER:

The answer was very simple and I managed to miss it. Thanks to: Daisy Shipton in the answers below I was able to track it down:

in his line: file = fbd.SelectedPath + "Video2.frf";

I forgot to add a forward slash before the file name, so:

file = fbd.SelectedPath + "/Video2.frf";

I'll keep this up and hopefully someone as silly as me will find it helpful!

Comment: What is `VideoProcessing` here? Is it your own type? It sounds like that could be where the problem is.

Comment: I'll that class to the code above. The files were saving earlier before I was building this so didn't add it, sorry.

Comment: It seems like this is the implementation we need to see, not all the other code: `processing.WriteToBinaryFile<VideoFile>(file, video);`

Comment: Just added it Rufus.

Comment: Firstly, I would definitely avoid .NET binary serialization as far as possible. Aside from anything else, it definitely won't create a video file that you can play anywhere else. Are you *absolutely certain* that you're looking in the same directory that the code is saving to? If you run this in a debugger and put a breakpoint in `WriteToBinaryFile`, then check the value of `file`, does that look right? The simplest explanation for this is that it's creating the file with no problems, just not where you're expecting it to.

Comment: I thought by this point of learning I'd be able to see such simple solutions. Anyway, the filepath was missing a slash before the file name and therefore wasn't saving in the right place. 

What would you recommend as an alternative to .NET and I don't want it to play anywhere else it was just a silly idea I thought up last night haha.

Comment: Check your logic - stuff like this if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath)) {
            file = fbd.SelectedPath + "Video2.frf";But then your code continues, so in theory, this could be trying to write to empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mary. I wrote what the actual problem was below and it was so simple.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid that problem as it automatically adds that missing slash